# How to use the method APEX_WEB_SERVICE.make_rest_request?

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to understand how the method APEX_WEB_SERVICE.make_rest_request works.

I tried the following code but I get the error ORA-00902: invalid datatype.

Does anyone please know how this does method work ?

Thanks.

```
select APEX_WEB_SERVICE.make_rest_request(
    p_url         => 'http://oracle-base.com/webservices/add-numbers.php',
    p_http_method => 'GET',
    p_parm_name   => APEX_UTIL.string_to_table('p_int_1:p_int_2'),
    p_parm_value  => APEX_UTIL.string_to_table(1 || ':' || 2)
  ) from dual
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement works in a PL/SQL block, as described in the Oracle documentation. Some of the functions parameters types are not available in SQL.

```
declare
  l_clob clob;
begin
  l_clob := APEX_WEB_SERVICE.make_rest_request(
    p_url         => 'http://oracle-base.com/webservices/add-numbers.php',
    p_http_method => 'GET',
    p_parm_name   => APEX_UTIL.string_to_table('p_int_1:p_int_2'),
    p_parm_value  => APEX_UTIL.string_to_table(1 || ':' || 2)
  ) ;
    dbms_output.put_line(l_clob);
end;
```